# ghostscript converting to pdf-a - icc file correct?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm using ghostscript 9.19 on a windows system.
When I run ghostscript from a batch file, it creates the pdf.
When ghostscript is scheduled from a program, it creates a pdf without content - there's just one blank page.
The command line is the same in both cases (one Long line, split up below due to formating):

```
gswin32c.exe  -sstdout=d:\my_data\gs_stdout.log  
        -dPDFA=1 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE 
        -sColorConversionStrategy=/RGB 
        -sOutputICCProfile=d:\my_ps_files\AdobeRGB1998.icc 
        -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
        -sOutputFile=d:\my_data\my_hopeful_pdfa_pdfa.pdf 
        -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 "d:\my_ps_files/PDFA_def.ps" "d:\my_data\my_hopeful_pdfa_pdfa.ps" 
        > d:\my_data\my_hopeful_pdfa_gs_out.log
```

*my_hopefule_pdfa_gs_out.log* never gets created. But *gs_stdout.log* does get created.

Whether a pdf gets created appears to be related to whether or not the *.icc file is present in the Directory where ghostscript runs.

I get different output in the stdout.log file.

When it works I get:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.19 (2016-03-23)
Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in (>)
Operand stack:
   false
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1201/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
```

The error log when it fails is:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.19 (2016-03-23)
Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in --file--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (AdobeRGB1998.icc)   (r)
Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1967   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   1836   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--       --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1201/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 818
```

Can someone help me with interpreting this output. AdobeRGB1988.icc in both cases resides in *d:\my_ps_files\AdobeRGB1998.icc* as specified in the command line.

Comment: You are using a forward slash at `/PDFA_def.ps` which is not a normal windows path separator. Try replacing that with a backslash. The other point is that the environment variables might be different when started from a program but without knowing what program is starting it in what way, this would be hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward slash is irrelevant, Ghostscript can handle either type, or both in the same path, as here (though I agree it would at least be sensible to stick to one or the other).

The actual problem is that it can't find the file 'AdobeRGB1998.icc' (in PostScript undefinedfilename means the interpreter cannot find a file) and without seeing the contents of the PDFA_def.ps file its impossible to say why exactly (because the file is opened in PDFA_def.ps)

However a plausible guess would be that in one case you are executing Ghostscript from the folder d:\my_ps_files, so the ICC profile file is in the current directory, whereas in the other case you are executing Ghostscript from 'some other' directory, so the file is not in the current directory. Clearly you modified the filename in there as that's not the default name, but it looks like you did not specify a complete path.

The 'as specified in the command line' refers to a completely different invocation, in this case you are using AdobeRGB1998.icc as the OutputICCProfile, however, PDFA_def.ps needs to use it to set the DestOutptuProfile in the OutputIntent dictionary, which is a different thing altogether and is **not** specified on the command line. This is because there is no way to create a dictionary object on the command line, so it has to be done in PostScript, and since the dictionary creation has to be done in PostScript, so does the creation of its contents, and one of those is the DestOutputProfile, and since that's read from a file you need to specify that in PostScript too.

You should put a full path specification to the ICC profile in PDFA_def.ps instead of just leaving it as implicitly the current working directory.

Note that the DestOutputProfile and the OutputICCProfile are different things, you do **not** need to specify a OutputICCProfile for high level output, that's a control for rendering, it has no effect here and I'd drop it.

The reason you get an error at all in your batch file is because '>' is a shell command, so if you put it in a batch file it won't work, it will be passed to Ghostscript as a command line argument. Luckily for you this happens after the processing is complete, so it has no ill effects. It wouldn't have contained anything anyway, since you've redirected stdout to a file.

Don't set -dNOOUTERSAVE unless you have a good reason, not simply folklore (there is a good reason for setting it, but you don't appear to be using it in that way). Unless certain specific conditions apply, this will do no more than potentially slow down processing (for complex reasons related to garbage collection).

Comment: I'm setting this as the answer. Setting the full path in PDFA_def.ps got the thing working. Removing -dNOOUTERSAVE made a difference in performance. You know your stuff. Did you learn it from the hard road of experience or is there a specific reference you have handy (other than Internet queries)?

Comment: Experience, I guess, I'm one of the Ghostscript development team (shh, don't let everyone know... ;-)

Comment: if I don't set the full path in PDFA_def.PS, will Ghostscript search through all paths in the path Environment variable?

Comment: Full path to what ? In any event Ghostscript does not use $PATH, so no.